# manipulating post order in Timber $context['posts'] object

Tags: timber

I'm trying to ensure the first two posts in my {{ posts }} object have thumbnails while the rest of the posts continue to order by most recently published first. I am trying to create a filter like so to accomplish this:

Filter definition in PHP:

```
function posts_with_thumbs_first_filter( $posts, $num_top_posts = 2 ){

    // find first posts with thumbnails in them to decide what posts need to be reordered to first position in the array
    $first_posts_with_thumbs = array();
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        if ($post->thumbnail) {
            $first_posts_with_thumbs[] = $key;
            if (count($first_posts_with_thumbs) == $num_top_posts) { break; }
        }
    }

    ...manipulate order of posts here...

    return $posts;
}
```

Use of filter in Twig:

```
{% for post in posts|posts_with_thumbs_first %}
    ...regular post output here, only with posts now reordered...
{% endfor %}
```

But it looks like manipulating the order of the posts is tricky because it's not a standard array, it's a Timber\PostQuery object with private iterators and methods inside that control the posts data. I can't use PHP's array functions like array_slice, array_splice, etc. because posts is not an array, it's an object.

Is there a solid way to manipulate the order of the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: convert the posts object to an array to enable usage of PHP's array manipulation functions.

```
function posts_with_thumbs_first_filter( $posts, $num_top_posts = 2 ){
    $posts = (array) $posts; // convert posts object to array to use PHP's array manipulating functions
    $first_posts_with_thumbs = array();
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        if ($post->thumbnail) {
            $first_posts_with_thumbs[] = $key;
            if (count($first_posts_with_thumbs) === $num_top_posts) { break; }
        }
    }
    $posts_to_move_to_top = array();
    for ($i = count($first_posts_with_thumbs) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
        $posts[$first_posts_with_thumbs[$i]]->moved = true;
        $posts_to_move_to_top[] = array_splice($posts, ($first_posts_with_thumbs[$i]), 1); // extract post from posts array
    }
    foreach ($posts_to_move_to_top as $post) { // put back into posts at beginning
        array_unshift($posts, $post[0]);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```